# How to change font size and font family in apple sign in button with react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-sign-in

I need to use apple sign in and I cant change the font size or font family. Ive been researching but cannot see how to do it. Only found a library 'react-native-apple-authentication' but would prefer not to use a library JUST to change the font family. Alternatively, I cant seem to find out which font family apple is using so at least i could give my other social logins the same font family.

```
import * as AppleAuthentication from 'expo-apple-authentication';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
        buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
        buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK}
        cornerRadius={5}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={async () => {
          try {
            const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
              requestedScopes: [
                AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
              ],
            });
            // signed in
          } catch (e) {
            if (e.code === 'ERR_REQUEST_CANCELED') {
              // handle that the user canceled the sign-in flow
            } else {
              // handle other errors
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```